# Batch Job RE-scheduling using Java , CronExpression

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jobs, crontrigger, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I have a job running which runs on a particular time every day.
I have to update the CronExpression of the Job using some logic, problem is once the CronExpression is update I have to reStart the server to run that job with new time.
How can I restart the job without re-starting my server.
I have searched through other problem but not able to find my solution.

My job to update the cronExpression for another job is as:

```
public void reSchedulerNotofocationjob(){
        List<Slots> slots=config.getActiveConfiguration().getSlotDetils();
        int size=slots.size();
        LocalTime slotTime;
        LocalTime currenttime=new LocalTime();
        String cronExp;
        BatchJobs batchJobs= mongoOperations.findById("5b1f69c21f74e5ecc0c607ea", BatchJobs.class);
        logger.debug("batch job id and job name "+batchJobs.getId()+" and "+batchJobs.getJobName());

        for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
            slotTime= LocalTime.parse(slots.get(i).getSlotTime());
            if(currenttime.isBefore(slotTime)){
                cronExp=slotTime.getSecondOfMinute()+" "+slotTime.getMinuteOfHour()+" "+slotTime.getHourOfDay()+" * * ? *";
                mongoOperations.findAndModify(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is("5b1f69c21f74e5ecc0c607ea")), new Update().set("cronExpression", cronExp), BatchJobs.class);
                break;
            }else{
                if(i+1<size){
                    slotTime= LocalTime.parse(slots.get(i+1).getSlotTime());
                    if(currenttime.isBefore(slotTime)){
                        cronExp=slotTime.getSecondOfMinute()+" "+slotTime.getMinuteOfHour()+" "+slotTime.getHourOfDay()+" * * ? *";
                        mongoOperations.findAndModify(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is("5b1f69c21f74e5ecc0c607ea")), new Update().set("cronExpression", cronExp), BatchJobs.class);
                        break;
                    }
                }else{
                    slotTime= LocalTime.parse(slots.get(0).getSlotTime());
                    cronExp=slotTime.getSecondOfMinute()+" "+slotTime.getMinuteOfHour()+" "+slotTime.getHourOfDay()+" * * ? *";
                    mongoOperations.findAndModify(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is("5b1f69c21f74e5ecc0c607ea")), new Update().set("cronExpression", cronExp), BatchJobs.class);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

How to restart the batch job..

Comment: Are you calling  scheduler.rescheduleJob to change the trigger associated with the job? If you do that then you dont need a restart. https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/Scheduler.java#L495